# TIZEN (Gear S2) Notifications are not appearing until I restart the Gear

Tags: tizen, samsung-gear-s2

I have followed exactly the similar approach suggested in the below two links and tested the application.

1. [Rich Notification](https://resources.samsungdevelopers.com/Galaxy_SDKs/Rich_Notification)
2. [Example Code - Hello Rich Notification](https://resources.samsungdevelopers.com/Galaxy_SDKs/Rich_Notification/040_Complete_Rich_Notification_Code_Examples/Example_Code_-_Hello_Rich_Notification)

But whenever I select to send notification, it never appears on Gear. But once I restart the Gear all notifications appears at the same time.
I have checked the settings to allow the app to send notification at device side.

I want the notification to appear immediately I send it from device which is not happening. I am missing any more settings?

Here are the logs get printed at device side when I send notification,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also stuck at same point that is solved now.

a) First Issue that needs to be taken cared of is 'Updating the Gear Manager'. After updating to the latest version the issue was possible to be taken cared of. (There could be some bug fixes). My history:

```
Previos version:
    Samsung Gear: 2.2.16070451
    Gear Plugin:  2.2.03.16071152
Current version:
    Samsung Gear: 2.2.16070451
    Gear Plugin:  2.2.03.16082251
```

b) Now Reconnect the gear from the scratch. Make sure You Perform a Factory reset and then connect and do not check restore settings.
//Just to play safe//

c) Sign in with your Samsung Account.

d) From your gear  open 'Manage Notifications'. Select All apps granting permission to generate notifications (or select some specific apps including the application you developed). To verify whether the specific application trying to notify is permitted to do so:

```
 Gear manager > Notifications> Manage Notifications > Select your specific app
```

e) Set 'Limit Notifications' to off. Limit Notifications Block notifications from appearing on the Gear while the phone is being used.

```
  Gear manager > Notifications> Limit Notifications> Off
```

Comment: My Actual problem was 'Limit Notifications', which has to be off. The settings says "Block notifications from appearing on the Gear while the phone is being used"